# Switch statement always executing default case when used in conjunction with prompt function

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I have written the following switch statement within my HTML:

```
<script>
    const day = prompt("Enter day number: ");
    switch (day) {
        case 1:
            document.write("Sun");
            break;
        case 2:
            document.write("Mon");
            break;
        case 3:
            document.write("Tue");
            break;
        default:
            document.write("Wrong Choice");
    }
</script>
```

The above statement is always generating the output `Wrong Choice` even when I am passing `1` or `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prompt` always returns a *string*, and cases are compared with `===` - a string won't be `===` to a number. Make your cases strings instead:

```js
const day = prompt("Enter day number: ");
switch (day) {
  case '1':
    document.write("Sun");
    break;
  case '2':
    document.write("Mon");
    break;
  case '3':
    document.write("Tue");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("Wrong Choice");
}
```

But `switch` is quite verbose and can be error-prone. Consider using an object or array instead:

```js
const days = [, 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

const dayNum = prompt("Enter day number: ");
const day = days[dayNum] || 'Invalid';
console.log(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess it’s that it’s being passed in as a string. Try to do

```
   <script>
const day = prompt("Enter day number: ");
switch (day) {
    case ‘1’:
        document.write("Sun");
        break;
    case ‘2’:
        document.write("Mon");
        break;
    case ‘3’
        document.write("Tue");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Wrong Choice");
}
</script>
```